# Creating a Drupal 8 Views filter plugin

Tags: views, 8

I want to filter the contents of all the views of my website. This should happen before the views pager is built. I guess I need a Views plugin then. First of all I want to create a views filter plugin, which will be recognized by Drupal.

On my way I have found an article about creating a views display extender. However this one is a display extender. I want to create a "filter extender". But I have no idea what I should specify in the annotation of the class, which resides in the

> Drupal\my_module\Plugin\views\filter

namespace.

I have tried this:

```
/**  
  * Filters views content.  
  *  
  * @ingroup views_filter_handlers  
  * 
  *  
  * @Plugin(  
  *   id = "my_filter_name",  
  * )  
  */
```

But the filter won't get recognized by Drupal after a cache clear. I was setting a few breakpoints there and the class is never invoked. Has anybody a hint or a good tutorial about creating a custom "views filter plugin"?

Comment: Are you also declaring the filter in my_module.views.inc within my_module_views_data()?